# Accessing an array inside a structure

Tags: c, arrays, struct

How do I access an array inside a structure, lets say:

```
struct example
{
double qe[2];
double qw[2];
};

double a[2], b[2];

struct example1 ={a,b};
```

How do I print a[0] for an example?
How do I print a[0] via using a pointer to the structure example1?

Comment: `struct example1 ={a,b};` is invalid syntax.

Comment: `a[0]` is not an array member _inside_ a structure...........

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: *last line of code should be "struct example example1" of course

Comment: It is still invalid because `double` is not compatible with `double*`.

Comment: @klippklar If that's what it should be of course, why don't you edit it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

```
struct example1 = ...;
```

is incorrect. You need to use:

```
struct example example1 = ...;
```

Even then, you cannot use

```
struct example example1 = {a,b};
```

to initialize `example1`. That is syntactically incorrect. You will need to use other methods for copying the contents of `a` and `b` to `example1`.

If `example1` has automatic storage duration, you can use

Method 1:

```
struct example example1 = { {a[0], a[1]}, {b[0], b[1]} };
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use:

Method 2:

```
struct example example1;
```

In some function:

```
example1.qe[0] = a[0];
example1.qe[1] = a[1];
example1.qw[0] = b[0];
example1.qw[1] = b[1];
```

or, Method 3:

```
struct example example1;
```

In some function:

```
memcpy(example1.qe, a, sizeof(a));
memcpy(example1.qw, b, sizeof(b));
```

Comment: What about
struct example example1 ={a,b};?

Comment: @klippklar, that is syntactically incorrect. In that context, `a` and `b` evaluate to `double*`, not `double[2]`.

Comment: You cannot use `struct example1`. Use `struct example example1`.

Comment: @klippklar What about it? It's wrong because it is trying to initialize `example1.qe[0]` with `&a[0]`, and`example1.qe[1]` with `&b[0]`. (`example1.qw[0]` and `example1.qw[1]` will be initialized to `0`.)

Comment: @klippklar In general, you can't copy arrays using assignment.

Comment: @RSahu Method 1 is only valid when `example1` has automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks R Sahu, i saw my mistake. It was indeed the wrong declaration of the arrays and the allignment with the struct. `struct example example1 = { {a[0], a[1]}, {b[0], b[1]} };` worked.

Comment: You should accept my answer and leave what you described here as a comment.